# What's the meaning of the word "nerd-crush"?

Tags: meaning

This is the context:

> I’m just going to come right out and
>   say it, I have a huge nerd-crush on
>   jQuery. I have for several years.
>   Actually, it may be more of a love
>   affair.

Comment: It simply means "extreme admiration for something, in a technical field."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *nerd* in "nerd crush" identifies it as decidedly non-sexual. It is a technical love, the slavering "fanboi" lust geeks (myself included) display when they encounter something of a software or hardware nature that is particularly delightful (i.e. "pushes all our buttons"). It borrows the term "crush" to indicate love or infatuation, but that is used semi-ironically. It is probably more of an obsession, really.

Comment: Fully agree; I would only make the subtle distinction that _all_ crushes are intrinsically obsessive in nature, which distinguishes them from true, mature romantic attachment.

Comment: ... as with for example machine code.

Answer (score 7):

It may also mean an admiration for a fellow member of a subgroup oriented around a technical matter or bit of fandom.

e.g., *I have a nerd-crush on Wil Wheaton*. This implies that I admire and appreciate his work, presumably reaching all the way back to his Wesley Crusher years, perhaps I follow his blog or twitter feed. This doesn't imply physical or sexual attraction so much as intellectual affinity.

Answer (score 3):

It could be defined as an "[infatuation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infatuation?show=0&t=1298541866) on a technical topic".
Since it could actually be a "love affair" means this is more than a temporary love or a short-lived passion.

Answer (score 0):

*Nerd-crush* and similar words are based on *man-crush*. The "crush" part of the phrase is ironic and indicates that the attached word is not something you could have romantic or sexual feelings for, but it's just so awesome that you do anyway.